# Themes and wallpapers are different in login screen and user screen!

Tags: login, screen, 14.04

As the title says. Things i did before this started to happen,

1. Updated to 14.04
2. Had cairo-dock but removed it

   - After updating, at log in screen i have "Adwaita" theme and that aweful purple wallpaper without the dots(i disabled those dots before updating to 14.04). But in user space i have the theme i want and the wallpaper(one of the default wallpapers).
   - I just want how things were before(i.e. default wall and theme, same in both log-in screen and user scr).
   - Why i am troubled is that, after i give password and press enter the screen freezes for 3-4 secs and top portion flickers showing so-many "Enter user id and password spaces", then when m successfully loged in everything runs fine (but sometimes when i click shut down/restart/logoff buttons nothing happens. So i have to use power button of my lappy to shut it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set same wallpaper to login and desktop

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
exit
```

with default wallpapers you won't get problem but if you want some other backgrounds make sure the file have sufficient user permissions.

if you have cairo-dock installed the and running at start-up the shutdown/restart/logoff won't work it is due to bug in cairo-dock.